# how to extract the IP from ansible getent wrapper module

Tags: ansible

I would like to use getent wrapper module in order to parse the contents of /etc/hosts and save the ip address in a variable for later use.  I do not manage to isolate the IP if found on /etc/hosts

we are doing this in order to check that the /etc/hosts on the server farm are up to dated we will use this variable to verify against the dns and if the two address do not match then correct /etc/hosts. I also tried slurp but without much success

```
---
- hosts: all

  tasks:

  - name: getent hosts
    getent:
      database: hosts
      key: "{{ansible_hostname}}"
    register: results

  - name: print result
    debug:
      msg="{{results}}"

  - set_fact:
     a_host_ip={{ getent_hosts[ansible_default_ipv4.address] }}


  - debug: var=a_host_ip
```

I would like to have the ip address in the varilable `a_host_ip` but the actual contents are the hostnames corresponding to the ip address. How can I save the IP address in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of IPs:

```
{{ getent_hosts.keys() }}
```

To get a single element:

```
{{ getent_hosts.keys() | first }}
```

Comment: hello `{{ getent_hosts.keys() }}` gives me an empty string. can you demonstrate how you chec the list of IP's ?

Comment: empty list means that there is no records in `/etc/hosts` for hostname `{{ ansible_hostname }}`.

Comment: actually no,  when you call getent with a key it does not work. i needed to remove `key: "{{ ansible_hostname}}"` from the getent task in order to have the ip in the variable. but then i do not know how to make sure is the ip of the host that is put in the variable.. and not other.. there is no guarantee that using `{{ getent_hosts.keys() | first }}` will show the ip of my host.